# Scala Month function throwing error No enum constant java.time.Month.UNDEFINED

Tags: scala

I am writing a scala month function that will return an Integer month number when called. This function is passing the compilation stage but throwing error while being called at run time.

```
import java.time.Month
import java.util.Calendar
object Test {
  val FINAL_MONTH_NBR = 12

  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    month()
  }
  def month(): Int = {
    val month = System.getProperty("month")
    if(month == null) {
      Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
    }
    else {
      val monthValue = Month.valueOf(month)
      if (monthValue == Month.JANUARY) {
        FINAL_MONTH_NBR
      }
      else {
        monthValue.getValue - 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is throwing error: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant java.time.Month.UNDEFINED** The error is at below line

val monthValue = Month.valueOf(month)

can anybody suggest how to fix this.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the posted error. Your code compiles and runs for me. I do notice that you're mixing the current `java.time` with the old and outdated `java.util.Calendar`. Probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of month names instead and set it if it doesn't belongs to list as given below.

```
  def month(): Int = {
    val month = System.getProperty("month")
    val monthList = List("JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER")
    if(!monthList.contains(month)) {
      Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
    }
    else {
      val monthValue = Month.valueOf(month)
      if (monthValue == Month.JANUARY) {
        FINAL_MONTH_NBR
      }
      else {
        monthValue.getValue - 1
      }
    }
  }
```

Don't forget to select it if it does your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess this line is the underlying problem:

```
val month = System.getProperty("month")
```

You check whether the value is null and handle that case, but what if the system property is `foo`? When you call `Month.valueOf(month)` there is no `foo` on the object, so you get the error.

Scala has useful features for working with exceptions which can help here. Consider the following:

```
def month(): Int = {
  val monthSystem: Either[Exception, Int] = try Right(System.getProperty("month").toInt) catch {
    case e: Exception => Left(e)
  }

  val month: Either[Exception, Month] = monthSystem.map(m => Month.valueOf(m.toString))

  val mSafe: Int = month fold(
    (ex: Exception) => {
      // see what went wrong
      println(ex.getMessage)
      // default case
      Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
    },
    (m: Month) => m.getValue
  )
  if (mSafe == Month.JANUARY.getValue) FINAL_MONTH_NBR else mSafe - 1

}
```

Wrapping the system call in an `Either` let's us capture the result if all is well, and the exception if something goes wrong. We can then use `map` like normal. It is 'right biased' so when we map over the results it just applies the function as if there were a value present, even if an exception were thrown. Normally you would probably just string all those calls together in Scala, but I've broken them out so it's clearer to follow.

Once we have a possible value in the form we want we call `fold` to handle both cases. `fold` takes two functions, one to handle the possible `Exception` case, and one to handle the possible `Month` case. Here we can use the first method to log any problems and return a default value.

Comment: exactly that is where issue is, but not getting any idea on how to fix it.

Comment: @palamuGuy, I've updated the answer with more details on how you might solve the problem.

Comment: `monthSystem.map()` here map is not recognized, it is referring to some less knowns scalaz library, that I have never used in my module.

Comment: `map` here is defined on [Either](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.10/scala/util/Either.html#map[B1](f:B=%3EB1):scala.util.Either[A,B1])

Comment: Use `Try(...).toEither` instead of `try / catch`

Comment: Looking for something simple that I can explain to others.